# Writing a Custom Script

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know how to write a script that will allow me to have a list become visible based on the text in a particular cell in my sheet?

Here is what I am trying to do:  I am trying to create personalized book lists for my students based on the specific classes they are enrolled in.  So, when I choose the class, I would like the book list to automatically populate so that I can create a list for each student without much time involved for each student.  Also, some classes may involve multiple books, so these would need to be on separate lines in the spreadsheet.  Is this even possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Tiffany. I think that you can accomplish this with a list of class / book pairs, and a FILTER or QUERY that references a cell containing a class identification. No need for a script. However, your question is quite broad. You should try those suggestions, and update this question with more specific details that you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you just go your sheet Data -> Validation then you can create Dropdownbox so to achieve your requirement create two sheet in your working sheet then  give validation finally do a connection with classes and books